# Xcode always pops up 'TV Out' interface

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

When I start my app, Xcode always pops up the TV Out interface with the simulator. How can I get rid of it？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the External Display setting of the simulator.
Go to

> iOS Simulator > Hardware > External Displays > Disable